# Пропорциональное изменение размеров, если картинка более...

Tags: imagemagick

Стандартный вариант

```
convert src.gif -resize 400x400 dst.gif
```

В данном случае, если картинка меньше 400px, то Имэджик ее растянет. А мне надо, чтобы маленькие (менее 400x400) не трогал, большие пропорционально менял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, делаем так

```
convert src.gif -resize "400x400>" dst.gif
```